# sqlalchemy update one table based on locked other table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I feel like I'm approaching this from the wrong direction, so feel free to provide suggestions that include restructuring my approach.

I've got 3 database tables, `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`.

`Bar` and `Baz` have `foreign key` constraints on `Foo.id`

Sometimes, I generate some new `Bars` for a given `foo_id`. Sometimes, this process takes into account the most recent `baz_id` if there is one.

I don't want stale `Bars` though; if while I was generating my new `Bars` with e.g. `baz_id = 1`, a different thread came along, inserted `Baz` with `id = 2` (for my given `Foo`), and added *its* `Bars`, all while I was busy programmatically generating `Bars` based on `baz_id = 1`, then I don't want my `Bars` anymore, because they're old news.

I want a way to say "only insert my `Bars` if the `baz_id` I'm using is still the most recent `Baz`, otherwise abort and throw away the work, I don't care anymore".

I'm **not** dealing with something like `IntegrityError` because I'm not violating any database constraints (e.g. uniqueness or versioning or anything); but I'm violating *logical* assumptions, that my most recent inserts are based on my most recent data.

How can I enforce this, in `SQLAlchemy`?

Comment: I wonder if a deferred constraint trigger could handle such a job – in other words this'd seem like a job for the DB.

Comment: Well, you can't force this with *SQLAlchemy necessarily*. You *can* instruct the RDBMS to use the [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/transaction-iso.html#xact-serializable) transaction isolation level - if it is supported.

Comment: Ah, ok, `SERIALIZABLE` might be the thing I need to look into. Thanks!